# Is there a way to build Dynamic Mongo query in C#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, dynamicquery

Could we able to build a dynamic mongo query where mongo query should process WHERE condition dynamically and retrieve the data from Mongo DB.

```
var query = from e in collection.AsQueryable()
                where e.FieldName1 == "XXX"  
                select e;
```

Here I need to pass FieldName1 as variable to filter based on user selection.

Comment: may i know how many Fields you have.

Comment: Just one field, but it would be in different collections based on users input i need to pass collection name and field name to get whole record.